# How to use a variable named 'type' in Scala class definition?

Tags: scala, variables, rename, scala-collections, conventions

I have to create a class that in its definition contains a variable named 'type', for example like this:

```
case class testEntity (
   type: String,
   val: String
)
```

Is there any possible to do that?

Comment: Other common workarounds are `tpe` and `_type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use names that are normally not allowed you have to put them in backticks (`).
Your declaration will look like this:

```scala
case class testEntity (
   `type`: String,
   `val`: String
)
```

Since `type` and `val` are both keywords.

EDIT: Also the convention in Scala is to start class names with a capital letter.

Comment: I've tried to use backticks but I've an error during compialtion: 
identifier expected but symbol literal found.
  'type': String,

Comment: I think that you are using single quotation marks instead of backticks. https://www.google.com/search?q=backtick&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikj6C8spLzAhVBEncKHULxDq4Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&cshid=1632307288709902&biw=1918&bih=957&dpr=1